# Getting rows in a Numpy array that meet several criteria

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I have the following array of data

```
In [56]:data
Out[56]: 
array([[  4360.,   6178.],
       [ 10906.,  14956.],
       [  5071.,   8963.],
       ..., 
       [ 16019.,  12300.],
       [ 12306.,   3327.],
       [ 13663.,  12641.]])
```

I want to store in `a` all the rows whose zeroth element is less than some value `value1` and higher than some other value `value2`.

I have try the following

```
d[ 9057 > d[0::,0] > 8000, 0::]
```

and

```
d[d[0::,0] > 8000 and d[0::,0] < 9057, 0::]
```

but both are stopped by the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there an efficient way for doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
d[(d[0::,0] > 8000) & (d[0::,0] < 9057), 0::]
```

By the way, you can replace all those `0::` with `:`:

```
d[(d[:,0] > 8000) & (d[:,0] < 9057)]
```

I find this a little easier on the eye.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. And yes, looks a lot "cleaner" with the `:`. Thanks!